# drop down sorting options not working

Tags: php, sql

i am trying to sort my products using a drop down box. when i select an option the code does not run and the products do not change position. iv managed to sort products by using different buttons but i think a drop down list would look better on a website.

```
  <?php
   echo $sort = @$_GET['order']; 
   if (!empty($sort)) {  
   echo $query="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY '".$sort."'";



    } else { 
     echo $query="SELECT * FROM products order by " ;
    }
    ?>


<form name="sort" action="" method="post">
<select name="order">
   <option value="choose">Make A Selection</option>
   <option value="price_asc">Price </option>
   <option value="price_desc">Z-A</option>
   <option value="name_asc">A-Z</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value=" - Sort - " />
</form>



<?php

//Run the query.

$record_set = $connection->query($query);

while( $row = $record_set->fetch_assoc() ) {


echo '<div class="product">'; 
echo '<div class="product-content"><h3>'. $row['name'].'</h3>' .'</div>' . '<br />'.'<div class="product-thumb"><img src="/ISD assignment2/images/'. $row['imageName'].'"></div>'. '<div class="product-desc">'.$row['description']. '</div>'. '<br />' .'&pound;'. number_format($row['price'], 2) . '<a href="../cart/cart.php?add=' . $row['productID'] . '"><p>Add</a></p>';
echo '</div>';





}
?>
```

Comment: Try to replace the line "echo $query="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY '".$sort."'";" WITH "echo $query="SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY '".str_replace('_',' ',$sort)."'";". Don't you get any mysql errors?

Comment: no i dont get any errors i tried your code and it does not work

Comment: Take a moment to think about this comic: http://xkcd.com/327/. Then read about SQL injection attacks and find out how to write safe PHP code that is not susceptible to them.

Comment: Oh, now I see it ... you have no action on the form!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Two potential issues:

1) Your Form has no action.  I believe you are trying to get it to refresh onto itself.
which would be:
action=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"

2) You are submitting via POST, yet using GET.
$sort = $_POST['order'];
```